# Grunt - plugin output -> other plugin input

Tags: gruntjs, swagger

I found a plugin (https://github.com/wcandillon/grunt-swagger-js-codegen), which uses a configuration like:

```
'swagger-js-codegen': {
        options: {
            apis: [
                {
                    swagger: 'swagger/auth.json',
                    moduleName: 'custom.dao',                        
                    className: 'AuthDao',
                    fileName: 'auth.dao.js',
                    angularjs: true
                },
                {
                    swagger: 'swagger/init.json',
                    moduleName: 'custom.dao',                        
                    className: 'InitDao',
                    fileName: 'init.dao.js',
                    angularjs: true
                },
                ...
            ],
            dest: 'src/'
        }
    }
```

but I don't want to add an object for every file.
**I wrote** a custom **plugin**, which **can read all** json **fileName** from swagger directory, but I don't know, **how can I add it to swagger-js-codegen**?

Thanks a very lot!

Comment: Can't you just declare a variable which is accessible from inside the two different tasks you have  (from a scope point of view)?  Then first run your task with which you get all json files add them to an array of objects and declare it to the variable. In your swagger task pass this variable to the apis option. I think what you actually want is a feature like gulps piping.